# encodeWithSelector and call equivalence in vyper

Tags: vyper, encoding

What is the encodeWithSelector (from solidity) equivalent in vyper?

For example, in solidity, if I wanted to directly the `transfer` function on our own contract using raw calls, I'd do:

```js
function callTransferFunctionDirectly(address someAddress, uint256 amount)
        public
        returns (bytes4, bool)
    {
         bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256(bytes("transfer(address,uint256)")));
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(this).call(
            // getDataToCallTransfer(someAddress, amount);
            abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, someAddress, amount)
        );
        return (bytes4(returnData), success);
    }
```

How would I do this in vyper?

> Yes, I'm aware we'd just call `transfer` since it's in it's own contract. But this is for the learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `concat` or `_abi_encode` for the `abi.encodeWithSelector` equivalence, and use the `method_id` function to get function selector.

The (near) equivalence of the above solidity in vyper would be:

```py
@external
def callTransferFunctionDirectly(someAddress: address, amount: uint256) -> (Bytes[32])
  call_data: Bytes[68] = _abi_encode(someAddress, amount,  method_id=method_id("transfer(address,uint256)"))
  response: Bytes[32] = raw_call(self, call_data, max_outsize=32)
```

- `method_id`: Gives you the selector
- `raw_call`: Is the `.call` equivalence
- `_abi_encode`: Is sort of the `abi.encodeWithSelector`